# How to gtest / gmock function accepting std::experimental::any argument?

Tags: unit-testing, c++14, googletest, googlemock, stdany

**Issue**

I need a help in fixing my unit test issue with gtest 1.10.0 version.
When I tried to unit test involving a function that accepts std::experimental::any argument, exception is thrown and unit test terminated.

**Steps to reproduce the issue**

Snippet of unit tests covering my test scenario available under https://godbolt.org/z/Y7dvEsaPf
In TestBoth testcase, if EXPECT_CALL and actual function calls are adjacently provided, exception is not thrown and test case execute successfully. But in my actual project code, my test function has call to send_data() function with both these data types.

**Tool and operating system versions**
gtest version is 1.10.0
Ubuntu Linux 20.04

**Compiler version**

g++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0
C++14

**Build system**

cmake version 3.20.5

**Additional context**

Help needed or please direct to where I can get this query asked and get resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `AnyMatcher` matches successfully any `std::any`. The solution is in forcing further expectations with help of `::testing::InSequence`:

```cpp
TEST(MockUseWith, TestBoth)
{
    TestMock mock;

    InSequence seq;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, send_data(AnyMatcher(EnableReq{true})));
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, send_data(AnyMatcher(ReadReq())));
    mock.send_data(EnableReq{true});
    mock.send_data(ReadReq{});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eaj4Pxb1T

```
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from MockUseWith
[ RUN      ] MockUseWith.TestBoth
[       OK ] MockUseWith.TestBoth (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] MockUseWith.TestOne
[       OK ] MockUseWith.TestOne (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from MockUseWith (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test suite ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, This solves my issue. Really appreciated the support.